# How to use properly \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

What I want to write is: -Index-remarks and notations-chapters and all but with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\title{Introduction}
\author{Dd}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Summary}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage  
\section*{remarks}
 stuff
\chapter{}
\end{document}
```

etc.. remarks are written right after the index.

Comment: Your question not is very clear IMHO and your MWE is not compilable: missing `\documentclass`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'remarks are written right after the index'? Do you mean they are written on the same page? What exactly is your desired layout, maybe you can make a screenshot, indicate what is wrong, and add that to your question? And as mentioned please make the MWE complete by adding your documentclass and packages that are relevant to the question, if any.

Comment: An Index comes at the end of a document listing words and page numbers. You are are talking about the Table of Contents, which normally comes near the beginning and lists division headings and page numbers.

Comment: So basically, I would like to see the section unnumbered before the table of contents as many books do.

Comment: Can you give an approximate idea of the intended output? Maybe an image from a book that does as you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand what you want, move the `\tableofcontents` after the end of the
`\section*{remarks}` and its text. The printing order will then be the title page, the remarks, the ToC and then the chapter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\title{Introduction}
\author{Dd}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Summary}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
% \tableofcontents
\clearpage  
\section*{remarks}
 stuff
\tableofcontents
\chapter{}
\end{document}
```

The source gets processed in order from start to finish (unless you use a package that changes this). For instance, if you put `\tableofcontents` just before `\end{document}` then it will be printed at the end.